# import csv with sporadic text qualifiers into sql server

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulk-import

I have a csv file that has fields with sporadic text qualifers (because some field information has comma in the value)

I know I can use a format file but can a format file deal with intermitent text qualifiers?

here's an example

```
5,Company A,1234 Main St, New York, NY, 11111
22,"Company B, Inc.",555 Best Ave, Detroit, MI, 48222
43,Another Company,"3344 Goodie Ave, Apt 2",Seattle, WA 98888
55,Something Else,7684 Something St, Nashville, TN, 37200
```

notice that the field that's text qualified could be any field

Comment: considering a udf that returns a table and perform a apply

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? Then come back and tell us.